# How do you extrude multiple faces inwards by the exact same amount?

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

I have the mesh on the left, and want to extrude the selected faces inwards by the *exact same distance* to obtain the result on the right:

[image]

I have tried "*Extrude Faces Along Normals*", which gives a strange tapered extrude:

[image]

and have also tried "*Extrude Individual Faces*", which gives an unequal extrude:

[image]

Is there a tool which extrudes them equally without doing them individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the scale in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), switch to *Edit* mode and Use *Extrude Faces Along Normals* but in the *Operator* box, enable the *Offset Even* option:

[image]

Comment: The "Offset Even" option does indeed straighten out the tapered effect, but on my machine it is not extruding the central one by the same amount as the two sides.

Comment: have you applied the scale in Object mode (Ctrl A)?

Comment: Ah, silly! Yep that's done it. Apologies.